# How may get number of participants in WebRTC room

Tags: javascript, webrtc

How can I get the number of participants in a conversation in WebRTC? I want one participant talks could learn about the number of all users in the room. Do I need to engage in a server? I am anxious to get this amount before operations on stream user.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have a server that take care of your webrtc signalling. That server is the one who will create the rooms and will have the information you are looking for. The number of participant in a room it is not something related with webrtc.